# How To Create A Directional Shield Impact Shader?

Tags: 3d, godot, godot-shader-language

This is an image of the shield's shader that I want to recreate in my project.

[image: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HbPTWSlws7Y]

As you can see, the impact shader doesn't works by lighting up an entire shield when it gets hit by the bullet. Because the impact area effect is limited, so only a small area lights up when it got hit by a bullet.

I try to do something similar with this, but I don't know how make this impact effect for the shield. I spent hours but couldn't find any tutorial videos about this, so I'm currently exhausted and in need for your help.

Here is the simple shader for the shield I made by following a tutorial:

```
shader_type spatial;

render_mode blend_mix,depth_draw_always,cull_back,diffuse_burley,specular_schlick_ggx;//depth_test_disable;
uniform vec4 albedo : hint_color;
uniform vec4 emission_color : hint_color;
uniform sampler2D texture_albedo : hint_albedo;
uniform float emission_amount: hint_range(0.0, 16.0) = 5.0f; 
uniform float rim_steepness : hint_range(0.0f, 16.0f) = 3.0f; //higher values mean a smaller rim.
uniform vec3 uv_scale;
uniform vec3 uv_offset;


void vertex() {
    UV=UV*uv_scale.xy+uv_offset.xy;
}

void fragment() {
    vec2 base_uv = UV;
    vec4 albedo_tex = texture(texture_albedo,base_uv);
    ALBEDO = albedo.rgb * albedo_tex.rgb;
    EMISSION = emission_color.rgb * emission_amount;
    float PI = 3.14159265359;
    float NdotV = dot(NORMAL, VIEW);
    float rim_light = pow(1.0 - NdotV, rim_steepness);
    ALPHA = rim_light * emission_color.a / PI;
}
```

Please let me know if you have any questions, and I will try to answer them as fast as possible. Thanks for your help and I wish you a good day.